# Calculation of G force

Tags: computer-science, physics, simulation

I have a formula which is G-force = velocity*omega/9.8. Omega is the angular velocity.
I've seen on the internet that G force is actually acceleration/9.8. I'm confused as to which formula is correct. For simulating the motion of particle taking a turn, would omega simply be velocity divided by radius of turn? Assuming Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: FWIW, there is now a [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) SE...

Comment: Oh cool! Will ask there. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For circular motion, the two expressions are equivalent.  Yes, in circular motion omega is velocity/radius.  Acceleration in circular motion is velocity^2/radius.